# Excel decimal rounding

Tags: excel

What is the excel function of rounding up the last decimal point?

```
9.23 => 9.25
10.26 => 10.30
9.25 => 9.25
```

Comment: How would 9.23 round to 9.25?  9.23 should round to 9.2

Are you leaving off significant digits, or are you trying to implement some sort of custom rounding?

Comment: yes, custom rounding of 0.05 increment

Answer (score 6):

Use the CEILING function to round up. To round down, use the FLOOR function.

```
=CEILING(9.23,0.05)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the `ROUND` function.

Comment: My mistake.  I didn't fully comprehend the question.  Matt Hanson seems to have gotten it right.